# How to fix TypeError in spyder?

Tags: machine-learning, python

How to fix TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer=Imputer(missing_values="np.nan",strategy="mean",axis=0)
imputer=imputer.fit(x[:,1:3])
x[:,1:3]=imputer.transform(x[:,1:3])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in 
>       imputer=imputer.fit(x[:,1:3])
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Nibir\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\imputation.py",
>   line 167, in fit
>       self.axis)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Nibir\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\imputation.py",
>   line 254, in _dense_fit
>       mask = _get_mask(X, missing_values)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Nibir\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\imputation.py",
>   line 30, in _get_mask
>       if value_to_mask == "NaN" or np.isnan(value_to_mask):
>
> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: How does your data look like?

Answer (score 3):

You might try it without the double quotes around the np.NaN and do not forget to import numpy (`import numpy as np`)

As a sidenote, you should use SimpleImputer instead of Imputer:

```
Imputer was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. Import impute.SimpleImputer from sklearn instead.
```